# sh: /sendmail: no such file or directory

Tags: php, linux, sendmail

The `sendmail` is working from browser but when I do `/usr/bin/php cron.php` from command line 
then it says

```
sh: /sendmail: no such file or directory...
```

I even ran `which` command and it showed me that `sendmail` is in `/usr/sbin/sendmail` and also, the `sendmail_path` in `php.ini` is correct.

Why is it checking `sendmail` in root directory from command line?

Additional: can we add a `sendmail` alias(shortcut) in root to the `sbin` directory?

**Edit:** The reason I am stuck with sendmail is because the standard mail library does not honor my return path.

Answer (score 1):

The way the `which` command works is it checks for the given executable in the directories that the variable `PATH` points to. The variable `PATH` can be changed to any desired value by using simple commands like `export PATH=SOMETHING` as and when you want it to point to different things. So I guess that if your `which` command points to `/usr/sbin/sendmail` when run from command line and still `cron.php` is not picking it up from there, then your `cron.php` might be changing the value of `PATH` somewhere or that coding has gone wrong and your code is invoking `sendmail` using absolute path.

First, make sure the above mentioned things are proper. And if they are, and the problem persists, as you guessed, you can [create a soft link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/creating-soft-link-or-symbolic-link/) and make `/sendmail` point to `/usr/sbin/sendmail`

Comment: I think you have a valid point because I am doing chdir. I have now removed that line and putting in dirname commands for file includes. I am going to try this again now.

Comment: Hi, I tested that without chdir and all files are being included with dirname(), The library I use is phpmailer but the problem is not solved.

Comment: @Khuram `chdir` might not be the problem. See the point where `sendmail` is being invoked and see how its being called. And just before it being called, also print the value of `PATH` just to make sure everything's fine. I place my bet on wrong way of invoking `sendmail` than on `PATH` being affected

Comment: I am not changing any sendmail or Linux path as I am using standard library phpmailer which has built in variable $SendMail = /usr/sbin/sendmail and even when calling this class, right before the send() function I am sending the Sendpath.

Comment: @Khuram I am only aware of linux stuff. No idea abt PHP. I've added PHP tag to your Qn. Hope you get some help from PHP experts